# Where to keep custom identities in windows form application?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, authorization, identity

I have a windows forms application that talks to several web services and third party components that requires myriad of logins based on username and password. Ideally, I want to keep a cache of username and password in my “windows” form application and I should be able to extract this when I want. For example, when I invoke sharpsvn client it requires NetworkCredential. The question is once I collected username and password for a service from the user, where do I keep them in windows form application and how can I retrieve them? I don’t want to pass username and password or (any object) of it around my method boundaries. The methods should know how to extract the credential from the current context. I would like to know a method where I can retrieve a saved collection of NetworkCredential  when I want.  What are my options? Is thread local storage is the place to store such information. Can I use CurrentPrinciple for this task? I have deeply nested methods calls and having a global hash table of such credential is not suitable.  I want to extract a collection of NetworkCrendential from current context. Note that this is a a windows form application not an ASP.net app.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your requirement is to only remember these credentials for as long as the application is running:

Are you using a common class for all your sharpsvn calls?  Then you can give the class a static NetworkCredential property - and then do the same for each of the services that you are using.  If it is null you know you need to ask the user, set the property and then use it from then on.  Obviously you will have to add logic to ask the user again if you do a call and the authentication fails.